# Proof about $\Delta u = 0$ for poisson's formula for half-space

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I have questions about the proof of Theorem $14$ (poisson's formula for half-space) in Page $38$.

> we easily verify as well $u \in C^\infty (\mathbb{R_+^n})$, with $$\Delta u(x) = \int_{\partial\mathbb{R_+^n}}\Delta_x K(x,y) g(y) dy = 0$$

I look up the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858657/questions-about-the-proof-of-poissons-formula-for-half-space-in-page-38-of-evan). I understand why $\Delta u(x) = \int_{\partial\mathbb{R_+^n}}\Delta_x K(x,y) g(y) dy$. The only thing confuses me is that $ \int_{\partial\mathbb{R_+^n}}\Delta_x K(x,y) g(y) dy = 0.$

So how can I prove that $ \int_{\partial\mathbb{R_+^n}}\Delta_x K(x,y) g(y) dy = 0$ then.

My question is why $ \int_{\partial\mathbb{R_+^n}}\Delta_x K(x,y) g(y) dy = 0$.

Comment: $K(x, y) $ is Harmonic, as a function of $x$, for any fixed $y\in\partial \mathbb{R} ^n_+$.

Comment: @Jose27 Oh I see. I was confused with the notation.